# Permutation of number by desired order

Tags: arrays, algorithm, permutation

I want to generate an algorithm for permutation of a list of distinct numbers in a specific order.
example :-
The numbers are

```
1 2 3 4
```

Order for permutation is

```
3 1 4 2
```

i.e. after permutation first number will go to third place, second to  first place, third to fourth place and fourth to second place.
Now the sequence for the numbers will be

```
2 4 1 3
```

Now if the algorithm continues to do permutation by same order then after some iteration it will generate the same sequence of inputted numbers and it will stop. For this case total number of iteration is 4.

```
2 4 1 3
4 3 2 1
3 1 4 2
1 2 3 4
```

I am doing this by taking another array `tmp[]` with two other arrays named `number[]` and `order[]`. Now I am just copying the elements of `number[]` in `tmp[]` by maintaining the position order for particular element from `order[]` and checking for same number sequence before next iteration. If another iteration is needed then 
    `number[]=tmp[]` and the algorithm will repeat previous steps.

Now if the number of elements are large E.g. `10^7` or higher then this method will run slow.
Is there any better solution to find the number of iteration?

Comment: What language do you want to do this in?

Comment: Do you need to actually generate the list of permutations or do just want to calculate the number of steps, after which you arrive at the first permutation?

Comment: I want better algorithm. Language does not matter.

Comment: You can try sorting in-place, this will probably be faster because you don't have to copy all the time, although it has worse complexity `O(n log n)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: I want number of steps for particular sequence and order.

Comment: Convert the permutation (what you call "order") into cycle notation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation and calculate the least common multiple of the cycle lengths.

Comment: This is equivalent to a question from a current CodeChef competition: http://www.codechef.com/JULY14/problems/SGARDEN.  Please wait until the competition ends on July 14th before answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate the permutation, your solution is already optimal because its complexity equals the size of the output.

However if you are just interested in the number of distinct permutations you can generate you can do much better:

- decompose your "order" in cycles: for instance `3 1 4 2` is one cycle `1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1` but `2 1 4 3` is two cycles `1 -> 2 -> 1` and `3 -> 4 -> 3`
- The number of distinct permutations is `lcm(n1, …, np)` where `n1, …, np` are the length of the cycles and `lcm` is least common multiple.